# PyQt5 Grab and save section of screen

Tags: python, key, screenshot, pyqt5

So the idea is that I should be able to fire up the script, select a portion of the screen, then hit enter (or otherwise trigger it) to save the selection.

I've got a good bit of the code from other posts and things, but now I'm stuck. I can select any portion of the screen and resize as needed, but I can't seem to get it to recognize the "enter" key. Right now the "keyPressEvent" function is just supposed to print a message so I know it worked, but I got nothing. Any ideas?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QScreen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QRubberBand


class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.selection = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)


    def keyPressEvent(self, qKeyEvent):
        print(qKeyEvent.key())
        if qKeyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return: 
            print('Enter pressed')
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(qKeyEvent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        '''
            Mouse is pressed. If selection is visible either set dragging mode (if close to border) or hide selection.
            If selection is not visible make it visible and start at this point.
        '''

        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:

            position = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
            if self.selection.isVisible():
                # visible selection
                if (self.upper_left - position).manhattanLength() < 20:
                    # close to upper left corner, drag it
                    self.mode = "drag_upper_left"
                elif (self.lower_right - position).manhattanLength() < 20:
                    # close to lower right corner, drag it
                    self.mode = "drag_lower_right"
                else:
                    # clicked somewhere else, hide selection
                    self.selection.hide()
            else:
                # no visible selection, start new selection
                self.upper_left = position
                self.lower_right = position
                self.mode = "drag_lower_right"
                self.selection.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        '''
            Mouse moved. If selection is visible, drag it according to drag mode.
        '''

        if self.selection.isVisible():
            # visible selection
            if self.mode is "drag_lower_right":
                self.lower_right = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
            elif self.mode is "drag_upper_left":
                self.upper_left = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
            # update geometry
            self.selection.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.upper_left, self.lower_right).normalized())


class mainUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(mainUI, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        label = MyLabel(self)
        pixmap = QScreen.grabWindow(app.primaryScreen(), app.desktop().winId())
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        layout.addWidget(label)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        geometry = app.desktop().availableGeometry()

        self.setFixedSize(geometry.width(), geometry.height())

        # self.setWindowFlags( self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = mainUI()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT**

Alright this code works, although to be honest I'm not 100% sure why.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QScreen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QRubberBand, QAction

class KpeWindow(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self,parent)
        main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.selection = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

        # label = QLabel(self)
        # label.setText('Test the keyPressEvent')
        # main.addWidget(label)

        # self.adjustSize()
        # self.setLayout(main)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.key())
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            print('yay')

        #QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'MDI', 'keyPressEvent')
        self.parent().keyPressEvent(event)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        '''
            Mouse is pressed. If selection is visible either set dragging mode (if close to border) or hide selection.
            If selection is not visible make it visible and start at this point.
        '''
        print(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:

            position = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
            if self.selection.isVisible():
                # visible selection
                if (self.upper_left - position).manhattanLength() < 20:
                    # close to upper left corner, drag it
                    self.mode = "drag_upper_left"
                elif (self.lower_right - position).manhattanLength() < 20:
                    # close to lower right corner, drag it
                    self.mode = "drag_lower_right"
                else:
                    # clicked somewhere else, hide selection
                    self.selection.hide()
            else:
                # no visible selection, start new selection
                self.upper_left = position
                self.lower_right = position
                self.mode = "drag_lower_right"
                self.selection.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        '''
            Mouse moved. If selection is visible, drag it according to drag mode.
        '''

        if self.selection.isVisible():
            # visible selection
            if self.mode is "drag_lower_right":
                self.lower_right = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
            elif self.mode is "drag_upper_left":
                self.upper_left = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
            # update geometry
            self.selection.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.upper_left, self.lower_right).normalized())

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #self.setWindowTitle('KeyPressEvent Test')
        # main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        # child = KpeWindow(self)
        # child.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        # self.setFocusProxy(child)
        # main.addWidget(child)
        # child.setFocus(True)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        label = KpeWindow(self)
        pixmap = QScreen.grabWindow(app.primaryScreen(), app.desktop().winId())
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        #new
        label.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusProxy(label)
        label.setFocus(True)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        geometry = app.desktop().availableGeometry()

        self.setFixedSize(geometry.width(), geometry.height())


        # self.setWindowFlags( self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set the focus policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) on the label to get keyboard events:

```
class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.TabFocus)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't seem to be printing 'yay' when I hit enter. Is there something else I'm not understanding?

Comment: @SuperStew. It works fine for me on linux. What platform are you on?

Comment: Ahh, I'm on windows 7. Is this one of those cases where windows needs a funky work around?

Comment: @SuperStew. Possibly. Presumably you must get keyboard events from the label when the rubber-band is hidden. Can you confirm that? It might also be useful to try with and without the focus policy change, or perhaps try some of the other policies, like `Qt.StrongFocus`.

Comment: Alright I got it to work. You were right, it did have something to do with the focus, but I had a hell of a time fixing it. I found a simpler example that I got to work, and just added in the functionality I needed (see edit above).

Comment: @SuperStew. Okay - glad you got it working. I did originally try setting a focus proxy, but it had no effect on my system, so I forgot to mention it. These platform-specifc differences are a real pain!